# How to get the child elements of with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML code defined like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="my_0" role="dialog"> 
  <!-- Rest removed for brevity -->
</div>
```

The point is that I have plenty of this in my HTML, and when I click one of them, the active one's class changes from `modal fade` to `modal fade in`. That's where I want to find some children of the active modal element. I tried both of the approaches below, but both of them return undefined.

```
$(function() {
    $("#SubmitBtn").click(function() {
        var location = $('.modal fade in').find("#location");
        var info = $('.modal fade in').children("#additional");

        alert("loc is: " + location.val());
        alert("info is: " + info.val());
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jquery you select the elements the same as you would in css. So instead of `$('.modal fade in)` it should be `$('.modal.fade.in')`. Making it:

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pyezEz)

```
$(function() {
    $("#SubmitBtn").click(function() {
        var location = $('.modal.fade').find("#location");
        var info = $('.modal.fade').children("#additional");

        alert("loc is: " + location.val());
        alert("info is: " + info.val());
    });
});
```

**One additional note** - You are using id selectors when searching for children. If using id's, there should only be one element with that id. Otherwise you should be using classes. If you ARE using an id and only have one (as you should), you can simply select it like `$('#additional')` instead of searching for it within another element.

Comment: Due to the question, they want modal.fade.in, but good answer.

Comment: Also, children and find will return an object of objects, or an array of objects. At bare minimum, they will need to do .first(), or use the :first-child within their selector.

Comment: That's making assumptions of what the user needs. Maybe they want all of the children.

Comment: true. I doubt it, but it's possible, especially with the next code looking for val().